# Best way to send file between Flash and Win form app

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, flash, embedded-flashplayer

I know that quick way of communication is ExternalInterface class, but this send params in XML form and might be waste of memory and cause performance hit .

How do I send/receive file/data to/from Action-Script-3 app embedded in C# WinForm?

Comment: You could send the file path and have the destination app open it. Or you could make the variable containing the file public, then do an externalInterface call which triggers a read of that public variable.

Comment: @Pranav Hosanhadi - yeah , this i know , but is there some direct ways to quick send bytearray ?  .  @ Chuck Savage - because im adding hard questions only :)

Comment: I haven't really explored this area much, but I suppose it would be simpler to send the path and have the other end open the file.

Comment: Yeah , but i was thinking to use C# as proxy for AS3 , to avoid any flash security problems and such stuff. I also think about Socket or Localhost , but for sure better would be some direct way between Flash and C# .

Answer (score -2):

You can use URLRequst in conjuction with URLVariables to exchange data between flash and any server side file.

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("<path to asp page>");

var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();


variables.content = content_var ;

request.data = variables;

request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onDataLoad)

urlLoader.load(request);


function onDataLoad(evt:Event) 
{
    trace ( evt.target.data)

    }
```